# WSO2 configuration using nginx

Tags: nginx, wso2

I'm using wso2am version 4.1.0 and trying to configure reverse proxy using Nginx. As per requirement i need to open devportal/carbon/publisher using the url provided in nginx configuration. Im able to open WSO2 directly using hostname, however using url provided in nginx I get **404 error**. Below is the nginx configuration. kindly help with suggestions

```
server {
server_name name1.com default_server;

root /usr/share/nginx/name1;
index index.html index.htm;

 location /abc/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass https://wso2dev.com:8243/abc/;
}

location /devportal/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        proxy_send_timeout 5m;
        proxy_pass https://wso2dev.com:9443/devportal;
    }

location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

}
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/name1;
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to map the root context to the target port. Otherwise you will have to add few more URL mappings.

```
server {
    server_name name1.com default_server;
 root /usr/share/nginx/name1;
   index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_send_timeout 5m;
            proxy_pass https://wso2dev.com:9443;
        }
```

Refer [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/) for a complete example.

Comment: I have made the same changes, however still getting 404 error. Is there a any solution for fixing this please..

Comment: @Chinnu add a screenshot of what you see. Have you added the correct DNS mappings for name1.com to point to the NginX server?

Comment: have added the screenshot.. yes, I'm able to connect to other applications aligned with name1.com eg: name1.com/abc/ however for wso2 im getting the errors

Comment: @Chinnu add your complete Nginx configs.

Comment: have added the complete config.. kindly suggest

Comment: @Chinnu as suggested previously create two server blocks, One for the Gateway and one for the Web consoles. Then map the root context, as I have shown you above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253552/discussion-between-chinnu-and-ycr).